# MySQL - bracketed list in UPDATE

Tags: mysql

The MySQL `UPDATE` statement does not work with bracketed lists.  For instance, the following is a syntax error:

```
UPDATE zork SET (A,B) = ('foo','bar') WHERE C = 'baz';
```

However, `INSERT` and `REPLACE` statements do allow bracketed lists.  Is there a way to group together lists of column names and values in `UPDATE` statements?

Comment: That syntax becomes cumbersome when constructing a query with dozens of tables, which is why I'm asking.  I'd also like to understand why the design decision was made, so that I can improve my conceptual knowledge of MySQL.

Comment: I like the row syntax but why is the alternative cumbersome?

Comment: This is the ANSI SQL syntax. MySQL supports many non-standard extensions to the language, but not this one.

Comment: It's cumbersome because you have to split up the column names, which you can usually hard-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row constructor syntax works in some places and not in others.

- **Works** in comparing with `=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `<>`:

  ```
  WHERE (a,b) = ('foo','bar')
  ```

  or

  ```
  WHERE (a,b) >= ('foo','bar')
  ```

  or

  ```
  WHERE (a,b,c) <> ('foo','bar',7)
  ```
- But **doesn't work** with `BETWEEN ... AND` and other constructions, like in `UPDATE ... SET`:

  ```
  WHERE (a,b) BETWEEN ('foo','bar') AND ('foo','bar')
  ```

  or

  ```
  UPDATE tableX SET (a,b) = ('foo','bar')
  ```

For why, only the MySQL developers can answer, I think. Perhaps you can submit a bug/feature suggestion.

For your Update, I don't think there is any other alternative than:

```
UPDATE tableX 
SET a = 'foo',
    b = 'bar'
WHERE C = 'baz';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key set and don't need to update that key, you could use the replace command:

```
REPLACE INTO zork VALUES ('foo','bar','baz')
```

If you really need to use the UPDATE syntax, you're out of luck.

Comment: There's no where statement in replace: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Sorry. Indeed, WHERE isn't possible/necessary because only the rows with the corresponding keys are replaced.